# Querying All Records of All Users who have any instance of purchase behavior in their history

Tags: subquery

I am trying to write a query that shows me all user ids that in any instance of usage have a particular type of "purchase credit" associated with their account.  I have one table, "users" that shows user information, ie, user ids, names, birthdate, etc. and then I have another table that shows all users all instances of credit purchases.  I want to pull all credit purchases (not just the type I am looking up) from all users who in any instance of purchase have this one kind of credit purchase in their record.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's common practice to write this sort of query using an `exists` construct, something like:

```
select *
from users join credit_purchases using (user_id)
where purchase_type = 'A'
and exists (
    select 'x'
    from credit_purchases
    where purchase_type = 'B'
    and user_id = users.user_id
);
```

Be careful that this type of query only works properly if you're looking for different records in the sub-query; if it is at all possible to "hit" the same record, you need to exclude that in the subquery's where clause, by doing something like:

```
select *
from users join credit_purchases cp using (user_id)
where purchase_type = 'A'
and exists (
    select 'x'
    from credit_purchases
    where purchase_type = 'A'
    and user_id = users.user_id
    and credit_purchase_id <> cp.credit_purchase_id
);
```

I'm assuming your tables have surrogate keys with the obvious names.

Comment: Of course, I was meaning to do that :-) Thanks, @ypercube.